# XF WebView (iOS 11): html anchors not working with local source

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I'm using a Xamarin Forms `WebView` and set the html as `string` to the "Html" Property of `HtmlWebViewSource`(which then is set to the WebView.Source).

The html contains anchors (**`<a href="#..."`**) to jump target inside the same html document. This works on iOS 8,9,10, **but not in iOS 11,** ie. you click on the link but nothing happens.

Any idea how to overcome this limitation ?

Answer (score 2):

Just found it myself: insert this js function under `<head>`:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function goToAnchor(anchor) {


        var element_to_jump_to = document.getElementById(anchor);
        element_to_jump_to.scrollIntoView();
         return false;
    }
</script>
```

Then instead of

```
 <a href="#myAnchor1">Some caption</a>
```

use this

```
 <a href="#" onclick="goToAnchor('myAnchor1'); return false;">Some caption</a>
```

where myAnchor1 is some element to jump to with id="myAnchor1"